# UDP in Java thinks that UDP has "connections"

Tags: java, sockets, udp

UDP in Java thinks that UDP has "connections".  This surprised me, coming from a C background where I had always used UDP as a fire-and-forget type of protocol.

When testing UDP in Java, I noticed that if the remote UDP port is not listening, I get an error in Java *before* I attempt to send anything.

What does Java do (without me asking it to) in order to be able to tell whether a remote UDP port is listening?

(The code below is run in the receiving thread for the socket.  Sending is done in a different thread.)

```
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(udpPort);
        socket.connect(udpAddr, udpPort);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "disconnected", e);
    }
    ...
    while (true) {
        // TODO: don't create a new datagram for each iteration
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[BUF_SIZE], BUF_SIZE);
        try {
            socket.receive(packet); // line 106
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "couldn't recv", e);
        }
        ...
```

produces the error below, if the remote socket is not listening.

```
java.net.PortUnreachableException:
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:556)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:516)
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.doRecv(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:161)
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:169)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:253)
        at com.example.mypkg.MyClass.run(MyClass.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
        at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:131)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
        ...
```

Comment: It would greatly help to better understand your question if you provide your code fragment in question.

Comment: Can you post the full text of the Exception?

Comment: This is not plausible to me.  Java Datagram Sockets do not have a notion of connections. I expect that you are misinterpreting the evidence in some way, but without seeing your code and the full exception stacktrace I doubt that we can get to the root of your problem.

Comment: @user1697575 I've added code and the exception.  It's Android, if that matters, but I'm confident I've seen the same behaviour in server Java.

Comment: @StephenC The error is `ECONNREFUSED`.

Comment: You are receiving, right?  Do you have perms to listen on the port that you are receiving on?  The `new DatagramSocket(udpPort);` creates the socket on a local port:

Comment: Also, `If the remote destination to which the socket is connected does not exist, or is otherwise unreachable, and if an ICMP destination unreachable packet has been received for that address, then a subsequent call to send or receive may throw a PortUnreachableException. Note, there is no guarantee that the exception will be thrown. ` from the docs here: http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#DatagramSocket%28int%29

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it is clear that this is not implemented using real Java.  The "libcore.io" packages are not part of the Java SE libraries.  These are Android stacktraces.  (This doesn't change anything ... but it could.)

OK, so lets start with the exception.  The javadoc for `java.net.PortUnreachableException` says:

> "Signals that an ICMP Port Unreachable message has been received on a connected datagram."

And for `DatagramSocket.connect(...)`:

> "If the remote destination to which the socket is connected does not exist, or is otherwise unreachable, and if an ICMP destination unreachable packet has been received for that address, then a subsequent call to send or receive may throw a `PortUnreachableException`. Note, there is no guarantee that the exception will be thrown."

So here's what I think has happened.  Prior to creating the `incoming` socket, something on the client system has sent a UDP packet to the server on that port, and the server has responded with an ICMP Port Unreachable.  Then your socket is created, and connected, and you call `receive`.  This does a `recvfrom` syscall, and network stack responds with an ECONREFUSED error code ... which Java turns into a `PortUnreachableException`,

So does this mean that UDP is connection oriented?

Not really, IMO.  It is simply reporting the that it received an ICMP message *in response to something that happened earlier*.

What about the `connect` methods, and the "connected socket" / "connected datagram" phraseology?

IMO, this is just some clumsy wording.  The "connection" is really just referring to the fact that the datagram socket has been *bound* to a specific remote address and port ... so that you can send and receive datagrams without specifying the IP and port<sup>1</sup>.

These "connections" are pretty tenuous and certainly don't amount to making UDP "connection oriented".

> What does Java do (without me asking it to) in order to be able to tell whether a remote UDP port is listening?

It is not doing anything.  Java is simply reporting information from a previous ICMP message.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, there is a bit more to it than that.  For example, binding tells the client-side OS to buffer UDP packets from that host / port an route UDP packets (and ICMP notifications) to the application.  It also tells it not to respond with an ICMP Port Unreachable.</sup>

Comment: ECONNREFUSED in UDP must be an Android-ism. The ICMP error that occurred shouod have been mapped straight to EPORTUNREACH. Java has nothing to do with that. Connecting a UDP socket is more than just binding. It conditions the local UDP stack to (a) know where to send to, (b) filter out incoming datagrams not from the target, and (c) route incoming ICMP errors back to the socket.

Answer (score 3):

> UDP in Java thinks that UDP has "connections".

No it doesn't, but UDP (regardless of Java) *does* have connected sockets. Not the same thing.

> This surprised me, coming from a C background where I had always used UDP as a fire-and-forget type of protocol.

You can `connect()` a UDP socket in C too. Look it up. What you describe has nothing to do with Java specifically.

> When testing UDP in Java, I noticed that if the remote UDP port is not listening, I get an error in Java before I attempt to send anything.

That's because you connected the socket. One of the side-effects of that is that incoming ICMP messages can be routed back to the sending socket in the form of errors.

> What does Java do (without me asking it to) in order to be able to tell whether a remote UDP port is listening?

It calls the BSD Sockets `connect()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The UDP server needs to listen on a local port.

Here's a code stub for a server.

```
int portNumber = 59123;
DatagramSocket server = new DatagramSocket(portNumber);

// read incoming packets
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
while(true)
{
   server.receive(packet);
   byte[] data = packet.getData();
   String text = new String(data, 0, packet.getLength());

   echo(packet.getAddress().getHostAddress() + ":" + packet.getPort() + " received: '" + text + "'");
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I didn't make my question clear enough for you.  My question is: How does Java/UDP know that the remote port is unreachable when I have asked it to *listen*.  If I ask to listen on a UDP port in C, it *sends* nothing on my behalf, so it *cannot* fail to listen.